# Linux TCP server, sending RAW data to few clients every X seconds

Tags: c, linux, tcp

I'm writing simple TCP server and I found some issue. Maybe you can help me a bit.
So, I wrote an echo server first (to test connection with computer client). It's working okay, but now I need to change it a bit. Server should sent char[100] to client when it connects and sent same char[] to every client every X seconds/minutes.

I've trying many changes, but application only crashes. Commented some of my "mistakes" in this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* BufferLength is 100 bytes */
#define BufferLength 100
/* Server port */
#define SERVPORT 6000



int main(){

/* Variable and structure definitions. */

int sd, wyslij, sd2, rc, length = sizeof(int);
int totalcnt = 0, on = 1;
char temp;
char buffer[BufferLength];
struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
struct sockaddr_in their_addr;

fd_set read_fd;
struct timeval timeout;
timeout.tv_sec = 15;
timeout.tv_usec = 0;

char datadata[100] = "This is a test string from server lol!!! ";

/* Get a socket descriptor */
if((sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0){
    perror("Server-socket() error");
    /* exit */
    exit (-1);
}else
    printf("Server-socket() is OK\n");

/* Allow socket descriptor to be reusable */

if((rc = setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&on, sizeof(on))) < 0){
    perror("Server-setsockopt() error");
    close(sd);
    exit (-1);
}else
    printf("Server-setsockopt() is OK\n");


    /* bind to an address */
memset(&serveraddr, 0x00, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serveraddr.sin_port = htons(SERVPORT);
serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

printf("Using %s, listening at %d\n", inet_ntoa(serveraddr.sin_addr), SERVPORT);


if((rc = bind(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr))) < 0){
    perror("Server-bind() error");
    /* Close the socket descriptor */
    close(sd);
    /* and just exit */
    exit(-1);
}else
    printf("Server-bind() is OK\n");

/* queue up to 10 clients  */

if((rc = listen(sd, 10)) < 0){
    perror("Server-listen() error");
    close(sd);
    exit (-1);
}else
    printf("Server-Ready for client connection...\n");

/* accept() the incoming connection request. */
int sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

if((sd2 = accept(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size)) < 0){
    perror("Server-accept() error");
    close(sd);
    exit (-1);
}else
    printf("Server-accept() is OK\n");

/*client IP*/

printf("Server-new socket, sd2 is OK...\n");
printf("Got connection from the client: %s\n", inet_ntoa(their_addr.sin_addr));

/* Wait for up to 15 seconds on */
/* select() for data to be read. */

FD_ZERO(&read_fd);
FD_SET(sd2, &read_fd);
rc = select(sd2+1, &read_fd, NULL, NULL, &timeout);


/* rc = write(sd2, datadata, sizeof(datadata)); */
if((rc == 1) && (FD_ISSET(sd2, &read_fd))){

/* rc = write(sd2, datadata, sizeof(datadata)); */

/* Read data from the client. */
totalcnt = 0;

    while(totalcnt < BufferLength){
    /* read() from client */

        rc = read(sd2, &buffer[totalcnt], (BufferLength - totalcnt));

        if(rc < 0){
            perror("Server-read() error");
            close(sd);
            close(sd2);
            exit (-1);
        }else if (rc == 0){
            printf("Client program has issued a close()\n");
            close(sd);
            close(sd2);
            exit(-1);
        }
        else{
            totalcnt += rc;
            printf("Server-read() is OK\n");
        }
    }
}else if (rc < 0){
    perror("Server-select() error");
    close(sd);
    close(sd2);
    exit(-1);
}
/* rc == 0 */
else{
    printf("Server-select() timed out.\n");
    close(sd);
    close(sd2);
    exit(-1);
}


/* Shows the data */

printf("Received data from the client: %s\n", buffer);

/* write() some bytes of string, */
/* back to the client. */

printf("Server-Echoing back to client...\n");
rc = write(sd2, datadata, sizeof(datadata));

if(rc != totalcnt){
    perror("Server-write() error");
    /* Get the error number. */
    rc = getsockopt(sd2, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &temp, &length);

    if(rc == 0){
        /* Print out the asynchronously */
        /* received error. */
        errno = temp;
        perror("SO_ERROR was: ");
    }else
        printf("Server-write() is OK\n");
        close(sd);
        close(sd2);
        exit(-1);
    }

/* Close the connection to the client and */
/* close the server listening socket. */

close(sd2);
close(sd);
exit(0);

return 0;
}
```

Thanks a lot buddies!

Comment: Where does it crash? Have you run this in gdb or some other debugger?

Comment: To start with you should learn how to use a debugger, for example the [GNU debugger](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/). If you compile with debug information (the `-g` flag to GCC/clang) and run your program in a debugger, the program will stop when the crash happens. You can then use the `bt` command to show a function back trace, to see how you ended up at the crash-site. If it's not in one of your functions, use the `up` command to walk up the call-stack until you are at one of your functions. There you can use `p variable` to print the value of variables. Check for e.g. `NULL` pointers.

Comment: It crash when I uncomment line rc = write(sd2, datadata, sizeof(datadata)); It's commented in two places in upper code

Comment: Looking quickly, neither of the `write` calls you have should cause a crash. Please edit your question to include the trace-back of the crash (i.e. the output of the `bt` command).

Comment: I wonder if your server is raising a SIGPIPE signal when a client process closes its TCP connection?  If so, you can suppress or that as described here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302873/preventing-sigpipe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to check out D.J. Bernstein's tcpserver (see http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp/tcpserver.html).  Basically, you can simply run your C program under tcpserver, and tcpserver will handle everything as far as setting up the sockets, listing for incoming connections on whatever port you are using, etc.  When an incoming connection arrives on the port that you specify, tcpserver will spawn an instance of your program and pipe incoming info from the client to your program's STDIN, and pipe outgoing info from your program's STDOUT back to the client.  This way, you can concentrate on your program's core logic (and simply read/write to stdout/stdin), and let tcpserver handle all of the heavy lifting as far as the sockets, etc.

Comment: Great thing! I'm after few tests and it's amazing. Thanks for you help, I really appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I ran your program against a simple TCP client code and did not see any crash. So, you probably should add gdb info to that. Also, in the program, I don't see where your programs wakes up periodically (you do have a comment) and sends data to the client. You should also consider adding the client fd to the list of read fd set and have one common select() call. If the select() returns a read-event on the listener, then that is a new connection and you should call accept. If the select() returns a read-event on a child fd, then you have some data to read adn you should call recv()/read().